# Is is possible to refresh a div with new content like stackoverflow?

Tags: jquery, grails, page-refresh

I having been working on a project, where when there is a new db update, we are using the `.click()` function to refresh the page to get new content into view, and that tends to load huge amount of data retrieval for a single update. But I have seen in sites like stackoverflow or linkedin they were loading the new content without refreshing the whole page.

May anyone help on how to add that feature in our project.

Comment: use ajax to update the content without reloading the page

Comment: @Sridhar R through with ajax function? hope I am not wrong

Comment: If you use PHP check this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6506873/change-div-content-using-ajax-php-and-jquery

If you use Asp.net check out the updatepanel control (http://ajax.net-tutorials.com/controls/updatepanel-control/)

Comment: @Sugunthan yes call the web service using ajax and get response append it to the div.this refresh the content not page

Comment: @Sridhar R yes, now I got it I think, let me to try with below given answer

Answer (score 2):

Use Ajax for this.

Build a function that will fetch the current page via ajax, but not the whole page, just the div in question from the server. The data will then (again via jQuery) be put inside the same div in question and replace old content with new one.

Relevant function:

http://api.jquery.com/load/

eg

```
$('#thisdiv').load(document.URL +  '#thisdiv');
```

Note, load automatically replaces content.

Refernce: [Refresh Part of Page (div)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17886578/refresh-part-of-page-div)

[Only update part of page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14832144/only-update-part-of-page)

Comment: thanks for your answer, but when new content is coming, how this will solve

Comment: Take for example,you have a div and only that part has to be refreshed,you are basically loading another url or data from the server..

Comment: And append the required data where you want it.(If its not a div)

Comment: k, thank you let me implement, hope you answer will help

Comment: Sure,do click on the tick if the answer helped you out.

Comment: sure i 'll do that after the implementation